# Calculate the domain of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am reading a list of files `filestoplot.txt` and load them to an array (`datasets[fileno]`). These 2-D arrays are similar in structure, and I wanted to calculate the max and min of each column (of all combined arrays) so that I can correctly establish the global d3 axis. However, my code (shown below ) does not correctly return `gloablmax` and `gloablmin`.

```
var files=[];
var datasets=[],totalfiles;
var i,j,dset=1,olddset=0,maxscale=0;
var maxnecr=0;
var cols=8;
var maxvalues=[];
var globalmin=[];gloablmax=[];

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function loadfilenames(){

d3.csv("./filestoplot.txt", 
function(file){
    files = file.map(function(d) { for (key in d) { fn=d[key]; } return fn; })
    totalfiles=files.length;
    for (i=0;i<totalfiles;i++){ 
        datasets[i]=[]; 
        loaddataset(i);
        maxvalues[i]=[];
    }
    if (filesloaded==(totalfiles-1)) maxmin();
}
);
}
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function loaddataset(fileno){
d3.csv(files[fileno],function(a){
    console.log("loading file "+filesloaded);filesloaded++;
    datasets[fileno]=a.map(function(d1) {
    return [
    +d1["f1"] ,
    +d1["f2"] ,
    +d1["f3"] ,
    +d1["f4"] ,
    +d1["f5"] ,
    +d1["f6"] ,
    +d1["f3"]/(+d1["f3"] + +d1["f5"]),
    +d1["f7"]
    ];
}
);
}
);
}
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function maxmin(){
for (j=0; j <cols; j++) {
    globalmin[j]=Math.Min.apply(null,d3.extent(maxvalues,function(d){ return d[j][0]; }))
    gloablmax[j]=Math.Max.apply(null,d3.extent(maxvalues,function(d){ return d[j][1]; }))
    //d3.extent(maxvalues,function(d){ console.log(d[j]);});
}
}

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

</script>

<body style="max-width:90%" onload="loadfilenames();">
<script>

function changedataset(el){
    console.log(el.checked)
    maxmin();
}
</script>
</body>
```

On the chrome console, I can see that maxvalues has the right data, however maxmin shows this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

I would be greatful for any pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply is only used twice,

```
Math.Min.apply
Math.Max.apply
```

If apply is a 'property of undefined', it means Math.Min and/or Math.Max is undefined.

It looks like you just have a capitalization problem, try `Math.min` and `Math.max` (of course there may be other problems as well, but that should be the source of the TypeError).

Comment: You are right. Just changing it to `Math.max` and `Math.min` solved it. I just did not realise that I capitalised it.

Comment: Another question: when would it be appropriate to call maxmin() automatically. I put it under changedataset only as a hack, but would like to call it as soon as all the data is loaded. adding it after the `for (i=0;i<totalfiles;i++)` loop, gives me an array whose elements are undefined.

Comment: When you say after the for loop, do you mean within the d3.csv callback (*right* after the for loop), or outside it? If it's outside the callback, that would mean it's probably getting called before the for loop, even if it's below it in the code.

Comment: with in the callback. Like so: `d3.csv("./filestoplot.txt", function(file){ for (i=0;i<totalfiles;i++){...} maxmin(); } );`

Comment: The problem may be that within the for loop, you're calling `loaddataset` which also calls `d3.csv` with a callback. So your for loop would be firing off a bunch of callbacks and then calling `maxmin` before they've returned. I think you'll need to keep track of how many `loaddataset` callbacks have finished and call `maxmin` after all the data has loaded. For example you could put a conditional at the end of the callback in `loaddataset` that calls maxmin if all the other datasets have already loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not fix it. I added `filesloaded` to the code (see edited question). `globalmin` is undefined when the page loads.

Comment: I meant that the conditional `if (filesloaded==(totalfiles)) maxmin();` should go at the bottom of the other callback, in `loaddataset`. That way it's checked *each time a dataset finishes loading*, and the last one of those times should evaluate `true`. If you place it in `loadfilenames` like this, you have the same problem as before; it's only checked once, after all the dataset loads have started but before the callbacks have returned.

Note that if you increment `filesloaded` at the top, you'd check for `(filesloaded==(totalfiles))` rather than `(filesloaded==(totalfiles-1))`